# Не отображается элемент nav:before

Tags: html, веб-программирование, menu, style, сss3

### Проблема

Вот html код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="~/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

А вот `css` код из файла `~/styles/style.css`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Suez+One');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav.menu {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav.menu:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0d0d0d;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

nav.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
}

nav.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav.menu ul li a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav.menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #909;
}
```

Если кто не понял в в этих файлах код горизонтального меню. Я это тестировал на сайте `cssdeck/labs` (http://cssdeck.com/labs) и там всё отображалось нормально, но в браузере это отображается не нормально: нет чёрной полоски. Если `z-index` поставить на `0` и выше, то не будет видно текста.

---

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите `background: #fff;` с `*` в `body`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Suez+One');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

nav.menu {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav.menu:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0d0d0d;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

nav.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
}

nav.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav.menu ul li a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav.menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #909;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="~/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.